# Reorganizing JSON data with associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have some data similar to the following:

```
let foodsArray = [
   {
        "food" : "fruit",
        "type" : "apple"
   } ,
   {
        "food" : "vegetable",
        "type" : "carrot"
   } ,
   {
        "food" : "vegetable",
        "type" : "lettuce"
   } ,
   {
        "food" : "fruit",
        "type" : "orange"
   } ,
]
```

that I would like to reorganize as follows:

```
newFoodsArray = [
    {
        "food" : "fruit",
        "type" : ["apple","orange"]
   } ,
   {
        "food" : "vegetable",
        "type" : ["carrot", "lettuce"]
   } ,
]
```

What is an efficient way to iterate through this information and build my intended result? I'm trying something like this, but syntactically it doesn't fly.

```
for (let i = 0; i < foodsArray; i++) 
     newFoodsArray[foodsArray[i]["food"]].push(foodsArray[i]["type"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
let foodsArray = [
  {
    food: "fruit",
    type: "apple",
  },
  {
    food: "vegetable",
    type: "carrot",
  },
  {
    food: "vegetable",
    type: "lettuce",
  },
  {
    food: "fruit",
    type: "orange",
  },
];

const newFoodsArray = foodsArray.reduce((acc, { food, type }) => {
  const isExist = acc.find((el) => el.food === food);
  if (isExist) isExist.type.push(type);
  else acc.push({ food, type: [type] });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newFoodsArray);
```